# How can I push back against my manager and HR trying to extend my relieving date?

Tags: human-resources, india, notice-period, relieving-letter

I have been working for the past 2.8 years in an Indian Corporate Company for a low wage. Now I got a very good offer from another company whom also supports me with good technology. So I spoke with my manager and sent a resignation email and he accepted it. My actual notice period is 90 days. Since I need to join earlier, I asked them to relieve me earlier and I will do the buyout.

They agreed to it and asked me to serve a minimum notice period of 45 days. The manager even sent me a mail regarding the relieving date which is March 20. Now a business head with a bad mindset comes in to the story and speaks with the manager and I don't know about it. I just know he is involved.

Now my manager says the mail he sent before is just a reference and that is not a correct relieving date. HR says the same.

**How can I talk with my manager to relieve me earlier?**

***I have a mail proof which clearly states my relieving date.*** But management is now trying to cover it up. **I have completed 43 days so far and if they extend my notice I will lose that other offer.**

Comment: @Shadowzee The question is tagged "India", which makes having relieving letters from past jobs more significant.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan My bad. Didn't know that was a thing. feels like a risky practice in general.

Comment: Have you told your new company yet that there might be a problem? Also, is this your first job? If so, could you consider not having a relieving letter from them?

Comment: Hey Naveen, try not to roll back good faith edits that improve the readability of your question. If an edit has changed things too much you're encouraged to [edit] again and restore your original intent without losing the work put into improving the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Tell your potential new employer what happened. Show them your proof. Ask them what you should do.

If they're willing to back you up against your current employer, you should have no problem.

Answer (score 3):

If your appointment letter says that you can exit the company by paying for non serving notice pay or for the difference of non serving notice pay, it should be legally ok to exit the company and the company can't stop giving all the clearance as required as under law if everything is as per agreed terms and conditions.

Handover all company property, pay for different of notice period, have everything documented..formally ask for all clearances...

If not complying you can approach concerned labour commissioner.