# Company is not releasing me and trying to hold me illegally

Tags: resignation, human-resources, india, notice-period, probation

I have resigned from company A after working for 20 days. In the offer letter that I had accepted before joining, there was no mention of probation clause (probation period being 3 months)

Now that I have resigned, after continuous follow up for 5 days. I told company that the 5th day is my last day.

But the company has not accepted my resignation and simply ignored it. Now after a week they sent me another offer letter dated in the previous date where they have added the probation clause and mentioned 30 days of employment in probation or recover salary in lieu of notice.

Not only this but informally they are telling me to be on Leave w/o pay which I have rejected informally.

What should I do for this unprofessional behavior?

And how to move on from this point?

Comment: Why do you mention what's in the offer letter? What does the contract you signed say?

Comment: in the initial offer letter that I had accepted, under the probation clause it was written that - 
" You will be on probation for an initial period of three months from the date of your
joining. This may however be extended depending on the performance during the
period. One is not expected to take any leaves during the probation"

Comment: @dan-klasson in India, a releasing letter is required, by failing to give him one, they're messing him up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I push back against my manager and HR trying to extend my relieving date?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/155086/how-can-i-push-back-against-my-manager-and-hr-trying-to-extend-my-relieving-date)

Comment: @gnat - it is a little different here. my future employer just needs a date to proceed, but here I am getting no reply from my current org. Also I was on probation, don't have any devices or so. even I don't have company badge.

Comment: @KatyayanVedant yes, perhaps its a *little* bit different, but that linked post is quite useful to your situation and you should totally read it and analyze the advise there given

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter: _"in India, a releasing letter is required"_ Is this then not something we cannot address? If it's required, I presume you mean legally, at which point either (a) the system intentionally gives companies the ability to not release employees or (b) the company is breaking the law. In either case, this is a legal question and in case of actual violation should be addressed via legal channels. If this "requirement" is not a legal one, then dan's point still stands.

Comment: @DarkCygnus: Thanks a lot. I read it in detail. Though I need an additional advice which is my future employer is supportive in terms of joining date and asked me to push the current employer for an exit date. This is to avoid myself linking to two companies at the same time. But I am getting no official response. This has become a deadlock. Since I have already mentioned my last day as 31st Aug, I don't know if I should use company email to communicate or personal.

Comment: @Flater: Indeed. Since there was no agreement on exit on probation, I am wondering if I should send a legal notice

Comment: Do they have any original documents? Why cant you stop going to office and ignore them completely? You did your part and let them do theirs. Are you worried about the pay for 20 days?

Comment: @PagMax: No they do not have any documents and as it is COVID times, work from home is being followed. I can ignore them and this is what I thought, but my future employer is asking for at least an acceptance so that later I am not associated with two payrolls. They have paid me for the 20 days.

Comment: You may have nothing to worry about then. Accept the second offer. You have given your resignation in written, in advance and as per your contract. If they still keep you in their payroll it is their problem.

Comment: ya sure. Thanks @PagMax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnat already linked you to a very relevant question you should read and consider ([How can I push back against my manager and HR trying to extend my relieving date?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/155086/how-can-i-push-back-against-my-manager-and-hr-trying-to-extend-my-relieving-date)). My two cents on your situation, given that you need the relieving letter to start a new job:

(from your comments):

> But I am getting no official response. This has become a deadlock. Since I have already mentioned my last day as 31st Aug, I don't know if I should use company email to communicate or personal.

Do whatever you have to in order to obtain an official response. I think that the most effective option is for you to **pick up the phone and call them**; if it's a possibility to *physically go to their premises* to talk to someone from HR face to face I would also do that.

At this point it's your priority to get out of this deadlock, as any further delay would only harm you (31st Aug just passed right?).

> Not only this but informally they are telling me to be on Leave w/o pay which I have rejected informally.

Then you should **reject it formally**. Don't leave it halfway done or informally. Make it clear and make it now. Making a phone call or visiting them would make this whole thing swifter rather than depending on them to check their emails.

Comment: Formally rejected it and spoke with them multiple times, but HR is saying that she needs to discuss with manager.

Comment: @TaichiKats I see... I suggest you talk to your manager in the new company that you are seeking to start with, and tell them about this so they can assist you (as suggested in the linked post)

Comment: Yes Thank you. I am in touch with them